Does LOTR have a shattered glass type alternate reality
Shattered glass is basically where the good and the bad team (morally speaking) switch, both within the general sides and individuals as a whole. It is primarily seen in The Transformers, but perhaps someone made a The Lord of the Rings adaptation of this idea.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It seems pretty clear that other than the corruption of individuals there isn't any case where the "good" and "bad" teams switch sides.  Are you looking for a specific fan-fic or something?

@DavidW I mean true good and evil can be subjective, but in transformers one side is clearly good and the other evil.

@Haridasa - The [story-identification] tag is meant for questions seeking to identify specific works which are known to exist (and have typically already been consumed by the person asking the question). This question appears to be asking whether there are any examples of a certain type of story, which is not what that tag is used for. In fact, such questions are normally deemed to be too open-ended for this site (i.e. new examples could potentially be summitted ad infinitum) and closed as off-topic.

The closest I can think of is The Last Ringbearer (1999) by Kirill Yeskov, which is essentially LOTR fan fiction even if it was published and is apparently well known in Russia (and has been translated into other languages). The conceit of the book is that Mordor was a thriving happy place that was overrun by envious and malicious opponents, and LOTR is an account by victors trying to bury the truth.
However that is a re-interpretation and a bit of a parody, there is no in-universe phantastical spell that switches good and bad around, especially since Tolkien himself would have hardly subscribed to the idea that "good and evil can be subjective" (and the Tolkien estate tends not to look favourably on attemts to rewrite Tolkien, or at least they used to).

I must that that The Last Ringbearer is a genuinely well written parody/fanfic. One of the few I can stand.
